# Best practice for returning the top 5 most occurring categories of each date into a dataframe pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to return the top 5 most occurring categories of each date into a dataframe.

I currently have this:

`result = df.set_index(g).groupby(t)[ng].apply(lambda grp: grp.nlargest(5))`

Where g is the category being grouped, t is the unit of time, and ng is the numeric value of g, which I obtain by factorizing g and returning the label.

When I print out that line, I see that the result given looks okay in the terminal, something like:

```
Date  Category <br />

1      "A"      15    <br />        "B"      10 <br />
       "C"      9 <br />
       "D"      6<br />
       "E"      2 <br />

2      "C"      30 <br />
       "F"      27<br />
       "B"      15<br />
       "D"      7<br />
       "E"      3<br />
...
```

Forgive my formatting, but these are essentially three columns, where the third column header is not populated, and the first column is not populated where the values correspond with the date given above. The numbers to the right of the Category column is the count of each category in said date.

The problem with this is that the dtype of result returns int64, instead of the dateframe that I was expecting. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: could you give an example of the output you want?

Comment: _"ng is the numeric value of g"_ & `result = df.set_index(g).groupby(t)[ng]...` -> numeric result?